# Ionic 4 build doesn't working on ios 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ionic2, ios10.3

“I’m using ionic 4 up, and want to support ios 10.3 fully. But unfortunatly build doesn't work on ios 10.3 but it works fine on 12.2”

Comment: Are you testing this in Xcode? Can you show errors?

Comment: yea I have tested it .On emulator it works fine but in device (iphone 5 with ios 10.3 ) it dos'n work

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Does the app not load at all? Does it crash?

Comment: I mean xCode generate the app successfully but device cant open it

Comment: It just dos't open

Comment: Read this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-webview-plugin-version-compatibility/151218/4. Make sure none of your Cordova plugins aren't a higher version than what IOS version you're wanting to use. If it's an iPhone 5, then there will be possible compatibility issues.

Comment: have you found solution??

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. This issue appears in iOS 10.3 because of splash screen and version of WKwebview plugin.

I did the following steps,

1. Downgrade cordova-plugin-ionic-webview to 2.3
2. Change in config.xml
3. In app.component.ts

   setTimeout(() => {
       this.splashScreen.hide();
     }, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

Steps to make ionic 4 work on ios 10.3, Xcode 10.1

in config.xml target 10.3

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="10.3" />
    ...
```

replace the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview version to 2.5.3 with the following commands

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@2.5.3
```

build the workspapce

```
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

in xcode open the workspace file (NOT the .xccodeproj)

```
projectname.xcworkspace
```

*Make sure that the Deployment Target is set to 10.3*

Select the Legacy Build System

```
File -> Workspace Settings -> Shared Workspace Settings -> Build System -> Legacy Build System
```

The issue is that they dropped the support for ios 10:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-webview-plugin-version-compatibility/151218/4